# Parent style sheet padding is not taken into account until after child is shown

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I set the style sheet of a widget, and then I add a child widget **after that**. But it seems that contentsMargins() does not return the real margins until after the child widget is shown.

Sample code:

```
this->setStyleSheet("QLabel {padding: 0px 5px 10px 15px;}");
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
qDebug() << label->contentsMargins();
label->show();
qDebug() << label->contentsMargins();
```

This is the output:

```
QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) 
QMargins(15, 0, 5, 10)
```

Note that if I were to swap the order, i.e. adding the child widget **before** setting the parent's style sheet, the problem would disappear.

But for various reasons, I can't add the child widget before setting the style sheet, and I also need to be sure that I'm not being fed false data from contentsMargins(). Is there a workaround to ensure that?

Comment: Does calling [`QWidget::ensurePolished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) make any difference?

Comment: Yes, calling it instead of show works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`QWidget::ensurePolished`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) to make sure the widget has the correct styling. This is what `QWidget` uses internally right before it is shown.